# Java.Swing. Закругление углов кнопки

Tags: java, swing

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите,как можно закруглить края кнопки?

Comment: Swing, JavaFX, Android?

Comment: Извиняюсь,забыл уточнить. Swing.

Answer (score 1):

Создаете класс `RoundedBorder`:

```
public class RoundedBorder implements Border {
    private int radius;

    RoundedBorder(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }


    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
        return new Insets(this.radius+1, this.radius+1, this.radius+2, this.radius);
    }


    public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
        return true;
    }


    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        g.drawRoundRect(x, y, width-1, height-1, radius, radius);
    }
}
```

Устанавливаете кнопке кастомный бордер:

```
button.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(10));
```

Взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3634480/7129209).

Comment: 1)При использовании этого метода,если мы задаем цвет фону,то элемент все равно выделяется квадратом.
2)Этим методом не получается сделать кнопку полностью круглой,ибо в таком случае,текст превращается в какие-то квадратики. (Кнопка большая,и места для текста много. Размер шрифта пробовал менять - не помогало)
Имеется ли какой-либо...стандартный метод,подобный "border-radius" из CSS? Или все делается только такими костылями?

Comment: @TrueASL, Стандартного способа я не нашел. Кстати, в JavaFX стили можно задавать непосредственно с помощью CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Дополню ответ @post_zeew:
Если кнопке задать фон, то он выйдет за границы нашей рамки. Это недопустимо. Для этого мы должны обвернуть кнопку в JPanel, указать рамку ей рамку и добавить в конец метода paintBorder:

```
((Graphics2D) g).clip(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(
    x + thickness, y + thickness, 
    width - thickness*2, height - thickness * 2, radius, radius));
```

Где thickness - толщина рамки. Если задаете setStroke, то это значение определяется вами. По умолчанию значение 1

Не забудьте проверить, что g - графика, которую вы получили в paintBorder. Если вы рисуете на графике, полученной через g.create(), это работать не будет